# JQuery toggle element based on click of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the beginnings of what I would like working but am afraid I'm not headed down a DRY path with my line of thinking.

Right now if you click any of the below divs it will hide or show a icon checkmark next to all the headers below.

I want only when a specific div is clicked to display the icon checkmark to the relevant header down the page.

What method should I use in my approach? The way I have it seemingly won't make sense down the road. Thanks for your attention and thanks for taking a look.

```
<div class="row container">
  <div class="row offset1">
    <div class="span3 frustrate_topside">  
      <div>
        <p>Click here to only show icon-ok element next to relevant anecdotes!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 frustrate_topside">
        <div>
          <p>Click here to only show icon-ok element next to relevant anecdotes!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 frustrate_topside">
      <div>
        <p>Click here to only show icon-ok element next to relevant anecdotes!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="offset2 span6" id='container'>
  <h5 class="faq_header"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Hey, it would be cool if..</h5>  
  <div class='content'>trouble</div>
  <hr>
  <h5 class="faq_header"><i class="icon-ok"></i> The kick is up! And..</h5>
  <div class='content'> 80% completion rate.</div>
  <hr>
  <h5 class="faq_header"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Third anecdote</h5>
  <div class='content'>joke on me</div> 
</div>

<script>  
$('div.frustrate_topside').click(function(){
  $('i').toggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: `<icon class="icon-ok frustrate"></icon>` HTML6?

Comment: But all the `<icon>` elements look exactly the same ... how do you intend to differentiate?

Comment: 1st please make the code valid. Then a little help would be to associate icons (not valid elements) with the divs

Comment: undefined- using bootstrap and giving the icons a class name because I suspect that is how I will need to differentiate these icons to do what I would like.  @pointy my thinking was to give the icons different class names. Then I would select those icons and toggle them based on the appropriate div being clicked up the page.

Comment: @JimmyKane My mistake in not indicating I was using bootstrap hence the icon "element." And to associate the icons with the divs I was planning on adding a class to the icons

Comment: No problem. Why not make something like <div id="dd_id_1"> and associate it with an if of the icon like <icon id="ii_id_1"> so that you can pair divs with icons

Comment: there is no `<icon>` tag... bootstrap docs tell you to use `<i>` tag

Comment: @Tmacram ok well then you can use a `data-` attribute on the clickable elements, and set its value to the class of the icons to affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working JS fiddle for what you're asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/sTve6/1/
I don't have your file set up with the icons/images, so I used placeholder text of 'o' for each icon, and made the assumption that your icons start out hidden.

HTML:

```
<div class="row container">
  <div class="row offset1">
    <div class="span3 frustrate_topside" for='q1'>  
      <div>
        <p>Click here to only show icon-ok element next to relevant anecdotes!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 frustrate_topside" for='q2'>
        <div>
          <p>Click here to only show icon-ok element next to relevant anecdotes!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 frustrate_topside" for='q3'>
      <div>
        <p>Click here to only show icon-ok element next to relevant anecdotes!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="offset2 span6" id='container'>
  <h5 class="faq_header"><i class="icon-ok" id="q1">o</i> Hey, it would be cool if..</h5>  
  <div class='content'>trouble</div>
  <hr>
  <h5 class="faq_header"><i class="icon-ok" id="q2">o</i> The kick is up! And..</h5>
  <div class='content'> 80% completion rate.</div>
  <hr>
  <h5 class="faq_header"><i class="icon-ok" id="q3">o</i> Third anecdote</h5>
  <div class='content'>joke on me</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon-ok 
{
 display:none;   
}​    ​
```

JS:

```
$('div.frustrate_topside').click(function(){
    var elt = $(this).attr('for');
    $("#" + elt).toggle();
});​
```

Comment: thanks for taking a look trismi. This is very close, but I want the other "active" icon-ok to hide when divs are clicked as they would no longer apply http://jsfiddle.net/7xC4P/4/. I also wish to have multiple headers apply to the top divs as more than one header will be relevant to the div. For ex: (in the fiddle) John goodman can be funny and smart

Comment: Updated to this: http://jsfiddle.net/7xC4P/5/ . I added a line `    $('.icon-ok').hide();` that hides everything, before the correct icon is shown.

Comment: Okay, I've updated it further so that you can add multiple ids in the for attribute. John goodman triggers two different headers below. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/7xC4P/7/

Comment: I should note that I wish for the "icon-ok" which is a checkmark to to appear and not the symbol that appears in the fiddle with is inside of the i element. Will need to take a deeper look to get the actual icon to appear and not it's contents.

Comment: I changed the .icon-ok class to float:left, display:block, and gave it dimensions so the space is always there. I then made a class called 'background' with a background image defined and added or removed that class when the header/name was clicked. If you don't care if the space is reserved for the icon, you can instead just set the background on the icon-ok class, and hide/show the <i> (as in the previous fiddle) instead of using the background class to add the background. Let me know if that's not clear-- http://jsfiddle.net/7xC4P/12/